# Convert jQuery Hover to Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to convert a piece of code from jQuery to Angular, and since I am super new to this I am not sure if I am doing this right.

Here is the jquery code:

```
$('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(300).fadeIn();
}, function(){
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(300).fadeOut();
});
```

What it is doing is when I mouseover a nav item, a div fades in.

This is what I have tried, but nothing happens:

```
angular.module("headToggle", ["ngAnimate"]).animation(".management-settings", function(){
    return{
        enter: function(element, done){
            element.css("display", "none");
            element.fadeIn(200, done);
            return function(){
                element.stop();
            };
        },
        leave: function(element, done){
            element.fadeOut(200, done);
            return function(){
                element.stop();
            };
        }
    };
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Is what I am doing overkill?

Comment: Could you do a fiddle? It looks correct

Comment: Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6hwbhcaj/ I don't know why I am getting an error though, it works fine on my dev enviornment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need Angular for this, you can do it with pure CSS:

```
.management-settings {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 200ms;
}

.management-settings:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

The full documentation on transitions can be found here: [Using CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions)

Comment: This doesn't have a delay, and does it affect a different item on mouseover?

Comment: I added a reference to the CSS documentation, see `transition-delay`.  This answer only affects items with `class="management-settings"`

Comment: I was able to remove `.management-settings` and do this: `li.dropdown .dropdown-menu`

Comment: I always forget about css transitions!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to chain a .animation onto the `element.css()`, e.g:

`element.css({'opacity', '0'}).animate({'opacity', '1'}, 200, done);`
This could also be accomplished with [ng-mouseover](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseover) to change a boolean variable bound to [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) e.g: 
`<div class=".dropdown-menu" ng-mouseover="hovered = true" ng-class={'is-hovered': hovered}></div>`

Then in your css:

```
`.dropdown-menu{
    transition: opacity 200ms linear;
    opacity: 0;
}
.dropdown-menu.is-hovered{
   opacity: 1;
}`
```

Previous answer is correct, you can use angular's built-in directives and pure css, and not have to write any of your own JS

Arg, I don't have the rep to reply to your comment on the previous post, but you can use the css property transition-delay